# How to delete all photos from iPhone using mac or pc

Tags: iphone, photos, macos

I'd like to delete all of the photos and videos from my iPhone 5S. I am willing to use [free] software on a mac or PC. Image Capture on a Mac does not have a delete option, before or after import. I imported all of the images and it did not offer any way to delete them from the iPhone. And, the instructions at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3075727?tstart=0 do not work for me since there is no delete icon visible.

On the PC side, the windows explorer delete function gives an error when I try to delete.

Is there an iPhone setting I need to change in order to make them deletable? Does this have to do with iCloud at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that if you disable iCloud photo syncing, then Image Capture will allow you to delete your photos.

Go to Settings > iCloud > Photos and turn off "iCloud Photo Library". Then, close image capture, disconnect your iPhone from your Mac, and reconnect the iPhone. Then Image Capture will show the delete icon.